# LinqPad - Query SQL Server View

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linqpad

I have a linq query that joins to a sql server view, that I'm attempting to debug. Can't seem to get it to work.

Does LinqPad Support Querying a SQL Server View?

Comment: Did you try to create a connection to your server/db? It is just under the Tables node.

Comment: It always something simple. The query to the View is case sensitive, in regards to the sql view name. Thank you for your suggesting, it got me pointed in the right direction.